# Get Magento 1.7.0.2 Logged In Admin ID From Custom Script Running On Same Domain

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I seem to have exhausted every example on google and stackoverflow. Please could someone tell me if this is even possible?

My script is in a folder along side the magento install. eg.

```
/var/www/app
/var/www/skin
/var/www/myCustomScript
```

I'm trying grab the current logged in admin id.

One of many examples I have tried.

```
require_once ("/var/www/app/Mage.php");
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$userId = $user->getUser()->getUserId();
echo $userId;
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the calling context? If you are trying to initialize the session from a context other than the browser which has the adminhtml cookie, you're going to have a bad time. If this is in a standalone script you will need to login via curl.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I want admins to login to the magento the normal way. My custom system then be accessed, it needs to detect if they are logged in if they arent then dont proceed, if they are then just get the admin ID so that I can use it to log who has done what in my script. Didnt want to make the users log in multiple times but if that the only solution then thats what I will have to do!

Comment: Sounds like you should configure an observer under adminhtml for the `controller_action_predispatch` and/or `controller_action_postdispatch` events.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
require_once ("app/Mage.php");
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session',array('name'=>'adminhtml'));
$user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$userId = $user->getUser()->getUserId();
echo $userId;
?>
```

Comment: This is what I have also, still no luck :(

Comment: I think you will see that `$user->getUser()` is not an object. Add this line before the `Mage::app();` call: `ini_set('display_errors',true); Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);` - this should hopefully give you additional info

Comment: Hi thanks for this, sorry I'm no pro but I am learning. This is a great bit of info to know. this is what I just got with the above example that you have given me. Fatal error: Call to a member function getUserId() on a non-object in /var/www/myCustomScript/test2.php on line 8